# Java EE or normal web application?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, jsf, jakarta-ee

I would like to know when an application can be called a Java EE application or a normal web application? Or could all web applications be called a Java EE application if they contain JSP, JSF, Servlets, beans, JDBC etc?

Could someone provide some insight into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A J2EE application is in a web application which is developed using the currently outdated J2EE technologies. J2EE does initially not cover JSF at all. It's more than often Struts, Spring and/or Hibernate.

J2EE has been upgraded to Java EE since the introduction of Java EE 5.0 at May of 2006 (yes, that's over 5 years ago!). Java EE 5.0 was the first to include JSF in the specification to supplant 3rd party MVC frameworks like Struts. Also JPA has made its way into Java EE to supplant 3rd party ORM frameworks like Hibernate. Java EE 6.0 was the first to include CDI in the specification to supplant 3rd party IoC frameworks like Spring.

I consider an application a "web application" when it runs on a web server and can be accessed using a web browser. I consider an application a J2EE application when it is a web application which uses outdated J2EE technologies. I consider an application a Java EE application when it is a web application which runs on at least Java 1.5 and uses at least Java EE 5.0 technologies.

#### See also:

- [Wikipedia - Java EE version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history)

Answer (score 1):

**Web Applications are subset of Java EE applications.**

Java EE comprises many technologies such as JDBC, RMI, e-mail, JMS, web services, XML, Enterprise JavaBeans, Connectors, servlets etc.

Web Applications uses limited web related technologies such as Servlets, JSPs, JSF etc.

Normally, Java EE apps are bundled in EAR archives and Web applications are bundled in a WAR.

Comment: FYI .. J2EE apps can now be bundled in war files as well using web fragments

Comment: If my application does not have EJB or JMS or web services, but have xml, beans, JDBC, then would it be called as a J2EE application? 
Application size is quite small with 10 or 15 database tables and I have a class for database connections, few DAO classes to read and write records from database,java beans and few managed bean classed for JSF. Of course web.xml,log4j.xml and properties files for other configurations. This could be termed as J2EE?

Comment: @aseychell FYI .. Web fragments  is considered to be a segment or whole web.xml. It is just part of the web definition

Comment: @Polappan Web apps can also use xml and jdbc technologies.